# MissingRequiredDependencyError aws-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have nodejs app which is being deployed as a lambda.   All of a sudden I find myself getting this error and I don't believe I've changed anything.

My understanding was that the aws-sdk didn't need to be packaged as a dependency given that those libs already existed in the lambda environment.

Has anyone else seen this and does this seem odd to anyone else?

```
Response
{
  "errorType": "MissingRequiredDependencyError",
  "errorMessage": "The \"aws-sdk\" package is missing. \n    Please, make sure to install this library ($ npm install aws-sdk).",
  "trace": [
    "MissingRequiredDependencyError: The \"aws-sdk\" package is missing. ",
    "    Please, make sure to install this library ($ npm install aws-sdk).",
    "    at Object.t.loadPackage (/var/task/index.js:16:1712339)",
    "    at t.Connection.loadOrInitiateDocumentClient (/var/task/index.js:16:1729895)",
    "    at new t.Connection (/var/task/index.js:16:1727956)",
    "    at t.ConnectionManager.create (/var/task/index.js:16:1725709)",
    "    at l (/var/task/index.js:16:1722093)",
    "    at Object.86184 (/var/task/index.js:16:995278)",
    "    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/index.js:16:2376966)",
    "    at Object.95413 (/var/task/index.js:16:995945)",
    "    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/index.js:16:2376966)",
    "    at Object.25860 (/var/task/index.js:16:976079)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: it appears that this is a specific dependency, which is not provided by Lambda. So you need to include it in the zip file and use that file to create the lambda function. Alternatively, you could also use lambda layers.

Comment: Thanks @Sri but that's my point.  it's the aws-sdk,  it should be provided by Lambda.  And I'm almost certain it used to be.  So in other words,  the error message makes no sense.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the code? I would like to try and see if I can resolve the issue.